# Formula for weighed geometric sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, power-series

I'm trying to find an easy way to derive a formula for:

$S_{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(n-i)x^{i}$

I've found a recurrence relationship of sorts:

$S_{n+1} = \frac{xnS_{n}+n+1}{n+1} = x\frac{n}{n+1}S_{n}+1$

But also:

$S_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}(n+1-i)x^{i}$

$S_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(n+1-i)x^{i}$ (as where $i=n+1$, $n+1-i=0$)

$S_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(n-i)x^{i} + \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{i}$

$S_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}S_{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

So equating these two:

$x\frac{n}{n+1}S_{n}+1 = \frac{n}{n+1}S_{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

$xnS_{n} + (n+1) = nS_{n}+\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

$(x-1)nS_{n} = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-(n+1)$

$S_{n} = \frac{x^{n+1}+(n+1)(1-x)-1}{n{(1-x)}^2}$

$S_{n} = \frac{x^{n+1}+n(1-x)-x}{n{(1-x)}^2}$

$S_{n} = \frac{n(1-x)-(1-x)(1-x^{n})}{n{(1-x)}^2}$

$S_{n} = \frac{n-(1-x^{n})}{n{(1-x)}}$

$S_{n} = \frac{1-\frac{1}{n}(1-x^{n})}{1-x}$

Or

$S_{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1-x^{n}}{n(1-x)}$

So if $|x|<1$, $S_{n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{1-x}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Questions:

- I appear to be making heavy weather of this (certainly the finite sum); is there an easier way?
- Is this series well known?

Comment: This series is probably the most asked question on this site. It's called an [arithmetico-geometric series](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Series.2C_sum_to_n_terms). While the series itself is well known, this name for these types of series appears not to be, which might be why many people have trouble researching it on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Lets set $G_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}x^i$, then:
$$ S_n = G_n - \frac{x}{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}G_n$$
From here we can derive finite and infinite sums - assuming, of course, convergence and possibility to swap sum and differentiation.